# Running into request limit trying to upload files via parse deploy

Tags: parse-platform, stripe-payments

I'm trying to upload the stripe node module which includes a lot of files and I'm running into "This application performed N requests within the past minute, and exceeded its request limit. Please retry in one  minute or raise your request limit." error trying to deploy.  How the hell am I supposed to upload these required files?

Comment: The Stripe node module would not work in Parse. Since it uses Node APIs not supported by Parse. I'd recommended using https://github.com/matthewarkin/stripe-parse. Its based on Stripe-Node 4.2.0 but re-wired to work with Parse's cloud code.

Comment: Oh perfect, thank you very much, i've been looking for something like that.  Works like a charm.